# How to manage newly created Buttons that aren't listed, Android Studios

Tags: java, android

I have setup this activity so that when you press the FloatingActionButton it creates a new XML Button and adds it to the LinearLayout. I want to manage these new buttons that I create, but I dont know how to. Do I need to give each button an individual name? Or put them in a button array? Here is my code and xml. Hope I explained this well enough.

Code:

```
public class CataFragment extends Fragment {

private LinearLayout mLayout;
private FloatingActionButton mButton;
private String newCataLine;

//private ArrayList<Button> buttonsList = new ArrayList<>();

public static CataFragment newInstance() {
    CataFragment fragment = new CataFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cata, container, 
false);

    mLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.LinearLineLayout);
    mButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());

    Button cataButton = new Button(getContext());

    return rootView;
}

private View.OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showChangeLangDialog();
        }
    };
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams =
            new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    final Button cataButton = new Button(getContext());
    cataButton.setAllCaps(false);
    cataButton.setTextSize(40);
    cataButton.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    cataButton.setText(text);
    return cataButton;
}


public void showChangeLangDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Create New Category");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            newCataLine = edt.getText().toString();
            mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(newCataLine));
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Don't Add", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        }
    });
    AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();
}
}
```

Xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_fragmentholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLineLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/InputText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/InputText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating new buttons that are textviews in `createNewTextView` you could create an `ArrayList<TextView>` to store references to all of the text views you've created then you could access them by their index.  If they have special ids you could instead use a map for easy retrieval.

Comment: I dont know how to give my buttons assigned IDs.

Comment: Well the id could be related to the data that you are showing in them, or you can use `view.getId()` but those ids are system assigned and not very meaningful

Comment: So what do you suppose i should do? Im really new to this concept, and i cant find too much on the web.

Comment: Maybe in your case use a map of the text they are displaying to the text view then if you want to modify them you can just look them up by their text? I'm not sure what you want to do to manage them though